# Voice recognizer or speech recognition that keeps listening to user's "input"

Tags: iphone, ios, speech-recognition, voice

Recently in past, I have jumped into iOS app development. I am onto conceptualizing an idea.

Does anyone knows about some service/class for voice recognizer or speech recognition that keeps listening to user's "**input**" in the background while you are on your App screen.

"**input**" in the sense of some speech/voice, Some words like "Go", "Wait")

As per my homework, I know there's `NSSpeechSynthesizer and NSSpeechRecognizer` available on mac, but not for ios.

Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenEars is an excellent option: http://www.politepix.com/openears/

You can create a custom list of words to listen for in your app and when recognized there are some convenient callbacks that provide the word and accuracy level at which it was identified.

You can also take a look at Nuance: http://www.nuancemobiledeveloper.com/public/index.php?task=home

From my experience if you are looking to identify key words open ears is a better solution, if you need to transcribe a paragraph nuance has the advantage.