# Always listening Unity IOS app

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, voice, listen, siri

I am building an IOS App using Unity. I need the App to always listen for some key words, a bit like Siri does. Then I can trigger some functions. 
I understand the larger voice recognition API can't really sit there listening & processing all day! 
What is the best practice for this?

many thanks

Comment: I was not asking how to add speech recognition, I can already do that. The problem is on the IOS you need to switch it on/off to talk. This seems to be accomplished on the IOS when you say "Siri". Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: This looks good https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788507/voice-recognizer-or-speech-recognition-that-keeps-listening-to-users-input?rq=1